# How to access a port that is already used by another Docker container

Tags: docker, networking

I am running a Tomcat server on one Docker container. On another docker container, i want to be able to access that Tomcat server. So, what I do is to use the -p option to map that port to the port mapped by the Docker container running the Tomcat server.

In short, I have the Tomcat container, which was run using something like this.

```
docker run ... -p X:8080 ...
```

And the other docker container like this

```
docker run ... -p X:X ...
```

However, if I try to do so, I get "Port is already allocated" error. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You can have as many containers as you want utilizing the same port number (for example `8080`) because containers run in their network namespace and there's no conflict. But when you bind/publish this port to a `host` port with `-p [host_port:container_port]`, you can use a specific host port only once.

Comment: I know, I was talking about the port on host which a container port is mapped to. Like the X in the above example.

Comment: Yeah, `X` here is the `host` port. You can't use the same number twice.

Comment: Also, by using `docker run ...` commands, your containers attach to the *default bridge network* which doesn't provide DNS between the containers. The easiest way to make 2 containers communicate, is to create a [user-defined bridge](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) and then you will be able to use their names directly, for example `container_A:8080`, `container_B:8080` from inside the containers.

Comment: That is a neat solution!

Answer (score 1):

When you add `-p X:Y` you are mapping Y port from container to X port in host machine and making it accessable in host.

Lets assume your tomcat container is running on `8080:8080`

Now you have another container running

You can access tomcat container inside 2nd container by internal IP.

If both containers are on default network.

Something like this `172.0.0.2:8080`

You can get assigned internal IP for container by this

```
docker network inspect bridge
```

or

```
docker container inspect $id
```

where id is container id

Comment: Never `docker inspect` a container to find out its Docker-internal IP address.  That address will change whenever a container is deleted and recreated, it's unreachable from other hosts, and on some platforms it's unreachable from outside Docker on the same host.

Comment: Yes True, Internal IP will change whenever we recreate or even start stopped container in different order. But as long as containers are up and running IP will remain same.